# How long did Bhishma live, after He fell asleep in the arrow in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

Bhishma has a boon that When they came to their mind they could have left their life. I know that he did not leave his life immediately after He has many arrows in his body. When did he leave his body?

Comment: Mukkoti ekadashi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bhishma lived for fifty eight days on bed of arrows. It was told by Bhishma in [Mahabharata, Book 13: Anushasana Parva, SECTION CLXVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b132.htm).

> The mighty Bhishma then, taking the strong hand of Yudhishthira, addressed him in a voice deep as that of the clouds. That thorough master of words said, 'By good luck, O son of Kunti, thou hast come here with all thy counsellors, O Yudhishthira! The thousand-rayed maker of day, the holy Surya has begun his northward course. **I have been lying on my bed here for eight and fifty nights**. Stretched on these sharp-pointed arrows I have felt this period to be as long as if it was a century. O Yudhishthira, the lunar month of Magha has come. This is, again, the lighted fortnight and a fourth part of it ought by this (according to my calculations) be over.'

Comment: Nice find! Btw did he die immediately after that or the Anushasana Parva teachings continued?

Comment: @iammilind Thanks. Immediately cast-off his body.